# MahApps.Metro textbox label/hint position

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

Is it possible to change the default position of textbox label?

[image]

Show "Date created" label on left, not on top.

```
<TextBox 
    IsEnabled="False"
    Text="{Binding ImpSport.CreateDate}"
    materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Date created" 
    Style="{StaticResource DialogTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

Comment: How is DialogTextBoxStyle defined?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `HintAssist.FloatingOffset` property to a `Point` with a negative `X` coordinate, e.g.:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"
        materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="test"
        materialDesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="True"
        materialDesign:HintAssist.FloatingOffset="-15, 0"
        Text="30.03.17"
        Padding="15 0 0 0">
```